# How do you say "growth development" in German?

Tags: english-to-german, vocabulary

Playing is very important to children because it helps with their growth development.

> Das Spielen ist den Kindern sehr wichtig, weil es ihrer Wachsenenwicklung hilft.

Is `Wachsenentwicklung` the right word in this context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use *'Wachstumsentwicklung'* instead.

Answer (score 3):

No. Waschentwicklung is not even a word (it literally means "washing development"). You probably mean Wa**chs**entwicklung, but that's not very idiomatic, either. I'd suggest "weil es ihr Wachstum fördert."

Comment: Or just "Entwicklung" if the context clearly points to children growing up.

Comment: It depends, I think. "Entwicklung" simply means development, not growth development specifically. But yes, the term as such is certainly used.

Comment: You're right. Hence the note about the context.